# What Is Motor Amps

Tags: power, motor

Just saw something on an electric dryer that said

230 volts

7.8 amps

7 motor amps

Does motor amps have to do with VA and Power Factor?

To clarify, the dryer was one that dries your hands in bathrooms and I am in the US, which I thought it was strange to run on 230v. It was operational though.

Comment: This is speculation, but I'm guessing that the 800mA difference is for powering the control circuitry, lights and sensors and not anything to do with the motor.

Comment: I agree, but that would be strange. I expect a dryer to use much of the required power to heat air.

Comment: Maybe it's some power-factor thing, related to motor/heater characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electric clothes dryer has two main components - the heating element and the motor. The spec label tells you the total current drawn by the dryer and they also tell you how much of that current is for the motor.

Also note that (usually) the motor current comes from one phase only (at least, in North America). That is: the motor is connected between one phase and Neutral (120 Vac).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by an "Electric Dryer"?

Hair dryers often operate the motor off a tap on the heating element so that some/most of the heating current also goes through the motor.  The voltage across the motor is very low so that the majority of the power is dissipated in the heating element.

Comment: I just clarified in the answer what the dryer was